# Finding the field type of GridView column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, field, web-controls

I'm working on an ASP.NET page that mutates to the MDB file fed to it. It currently allows you to choose a table to work with, and from there what row to edit, and fills the page with text boxes and fills them with data. This all works but it poses a problem when it isn't a string based field type, for example, what I have a problem with is determining when the cell being targeted is a CheckBoxField type.

My question would be, how can you get the column web control value from a filled GridView?

Comment: Are you using Item templates for Column view or Simply binding datasource??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you have access to the table? You can try getting the type fron the column collection (table.Columns[name].DataType (from the top of my head)

You can then use the column type to select a control.

Comment: on the right track, turns out GetType() returns the value I was looking for, new problems arise but not i can move on.  Passed by this while working on it but as I was looking at a specified cell it wasn't passing the data I was looking for, looking at the column works however. Now I just need to get it to work with autogeneratecolumns on...

Answer (score 0):

I think you want your grid to behave somthing like example explained:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37207/Editable-Gridview-with-Textbox-CheckBox-Radio-Butt

Download source code for your refrence.
Hope this will help.